# TikZ, fill the space between two paths

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-node, intersections, fillbetween, tikz-path

I would like to fill the space between the central semi-circumference and the solid black lines above.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=1.5cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections,spath3,pgfplots.fillbetween}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (orig1) at (0,0);
\path [spath/save=orig1--A, line width=0.5mm, red] (orig1) arc[start angle=0, end angle=180, radius=5cm] coordinate (A);
\coordinate (orig2) at ($(orig1)!0.5!(A)$);
\path [spath/save=orig2--B, line width=0.5mm, red] (orig2) arc[start angle=0, end angle=180, radius=5cm] coordinate (B);
\path [draw,name intersections={of=orig1--A and orig2--B,by=E}];
\tikzset
{% spath3 operatios:
   spath/split at intersections={orig1--A}{orig2--B},
   spath/get components of={orig1--A}\Acpts,
   spath/get components of={orig2--B}\Bcpts
}
\draw[line width=0.5mm,gray,dashed,
      spath/use=\getComponentOf\Acpts{1},
      spath/use={\getComponentOf\Bcpts{2},weld}];
\draw[name path=smerge, line width=0.5mm,
      spath/use=\getComponentOf\Acpts{2},spath/use=\getComponentOf\Bcpts{1}];
      
\draw[line width=0.25mm,dotted] ([shift=({-1,0})]B)--([shift=({1,0})]orig1);

\path [draw, name path=s3, line width=0.5mm, gray] (orig2) arc[start angle=0, end angle=180, radius=2.5cm];

\tikzfillbetween[of=smerge and s3]{blue, opacity=0.2};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

For this reason, I called `smerge` the path which includes both the two solid black lines and `s3` the path of the semi-circumference. Then, I simply tried

```
\tikzfillbetween[of=smerge and s3]{blue, opacity=0.2};
```

But this is the result:

[image]

The desired area is filled, but also a sort of triangle is filled, starting from the extreme points of the semi-circumference. How can I avoid this and fill only the space between `smerge` and `s3`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you're currently using `spath3` you can combine the 3 arcs 'welding' them to form a solid (so there is no need for `fillbetween`).

Something like this:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=1.618mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections,spath3}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (orig1) at (0,0);
\path [spath/save=orig1--A] (orig1) arc[start angle=0, end angle=180, radius=5cm] coordinate (A);
\coordinate (orig2) at ($(orig1)!0.5!(A)$);
\path [spath/save=orig2--B] (orig2) arc[start angle=0, end angle=180, radius=5cm] coordinate (B);
\path [draw,name intersections={of=orig1--A and orig2--B,by=E}];
\node at (E)[circle,fill,red] {};
% creating the 'gray' arc and saving it (it will be gray)
\path [spath/save=s3] (orig2) arc[start angle=0, end angle=180, radius=2.5cm];
\tikzset
{% spath3 operatios:
   spath/split at intersections={orig1--A}{orig2--B},
   spath/get components of={orig1--A}\Acpts,
   spath/get components of={orig2--B}\Bcpts
}
\draw[line width=0.5mm,gray,dashed,
      spath/use=\getComponentOf\Acpts{1},
      spath/use={\getComponentOf\Bcpts{2},weld}];
\draw[name path=smerge, line width=0.5mm,
      spath/use=\getComponentOf\Acpts{2},spath/use=\getComponentOf\Bcpts{1}];
% drawing the saved gray path
\draw[spath/use=s3,line width=0.5mm, gray];
% combining various arcs in one solid
\fill[blue, opacity=0.2,
      spath/use={\getComponentOf\Acpts{2},reverse},
      spath/use={\getComponentOf\Bcpts{1},reverse,weld},
      spath/use={s3,weld}
     ];
\draw[line width=0.25mm,dotted] ([shift=({-1,0})]B)--([shift=({1,0})]orig1);
%\tikzfillbetween[of=smerge and s3]{blue, opacity=0.2};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 8):

Just a simpler solution without the unneeded fancy packages.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\newcommand{\radius}{3cm}
\draw[gray, thick, dotted] (-2*\radius-1,0) -- (2*\radius+1,0);
\draw[gray, ultra thick, dotted] (0.5*\radius,0) arc[start angle=0, end angle=180, radius=\radius];
\draw[gray, ultra thick, dotted] (-0.5*\radius,0) arc[start angle=180, end angle=0, radius=\radius];
\draw[ultra thick, fill=blue!20] (0.5*\radius,0) arc[start angle=0, end angle=180, radius=0.5*\radius] arc[start angle=0, end angle=-60, radius=-\radius] arc[start angle=60, end angle=0, radius=\radius] -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Arcs with filled area]

Comment: Very simple solution!(+1))

Answer (score 4):

#### Adaptations

- Just change the order of `\Bcpts{1}` and `\Acpts{2}`:

  ```
  \draw[name path=smerge, line width=0.5mm,
        spath/use=\getComponentOf\Bcpts{1},
        spath/use=\getComponentOf\Acpts{2}];
  ```

  This means: first draw the left part of right arc (B), then the right part of left arc (A). This kind of problem can mostly be changed by correcting the order.

#### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=1.5cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections,spath3,pgfplots.fillbetween}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (orig1) at (0,0);
\path [spath/save=orig1--A, line width=0.5mm, red] (orig1) arc[start angle=0, end angle=180, radius=5cm] coordinate (A);
\coordinate (orig2) at ($(orig1)!0.5!(A)$);
\path [spath/save=orig2--B, line width=0.5mm, red] (orig2) arc[start angle=0, end angle=180, radius=5cm] coordinate (B);
\path [draw,name intersections={of=orig1--A and orig2--B,by=E}];
\tikzset
{% spath3 operatios:
   spath/split at intersections={orig1--A}{orig2--B},
   spath/get components of={orig1--A}\Acpts,
   spath/get components of={orig2--B}\Bcpts
}
\draw[line width=0.5mm,gray,dashed,
      spath/use=\getComponentOf\Acpts{1},
      spath/use={\getComponentOf\Bcpts{2},weld}];
\draw[name path=smerge, line width=0.5mm,
      spath/use=\getComponentOf\Bcpts{1},
      spath/use=\getComponentOf\Acpts{2}];
      
\draw[line width=0.25mm,dotted] ([shift=({-1,0})]B)--([shift=({1,0})]orig1);

\path [draw, name path=s3, line width=0.5mm, gray] (orig2) arc[start angle=0, end angle=180, radius=2.5cm];

\tikzfillbetween[of=smerge and s3]{blue, opacity=0.2};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

#### Result

[image]

Answer (score 2):

<s>While you are waiting for answers to your Tikz questions,</s> here is a `lualatex` alternative using the built-in [Metapost](http://www.tug.org/metapost.html) language.

[image]

You need to compile this with `lualatex`:

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\begin{document}
\mplibtextextlabel{enable}
\begin{mplibcode}
input colorbrewer-rgb
beginfig(1);
  numeric r, s; r = 144; s = 60;
  path a, b, c, base, shark;
  a = halfcircle scaled 2r shifted (s * right);
  b = halfcircle scaled 2r shifted (s * left);
  c = halfcircle scaled abs (point 0 of b - point 4 of a);
  base = point 4 of b shifted 20 left -- point 0 of a shifted 20 right;
  shark = buildcycle(b, a, reverse c);

  fill shark withcolor Blues 8 3;
  fill c -- cycle withcolor Oranges 8 2;
  draw a dashed evenly;
  draw b dashed evenly;
  draw shark;
  draw base dashed withdots scaled 1/2;

endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

#### Notes

- The [colorbrewer](https://colorbrewer2.org/) colour definitions for MP are [part of a full texmf installation](https://ctan.org/pkg/metapost-colorbrewer?lang=en).
- The built-in `halfcircle` path has five points numbered from 0 (at 3 o'clock) to 4 (at 9 o'clock).
- The `buildcycle` macro takes a list of `<path>` variables, and attempts to combine them into a closed path.  It works best if you list the paths in the right order, and have them all running in the same direction round the cycle.  Hence `buildcycle(a, b, reverse c)`.
- You can only `fill` closed paths, hence you have to do `fill c--cycle` rather than just `fill c`.
- Filling and drawing are separate operations in MP.